# Fail to run Tensorflow examples on Windows

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I followed the instructions online and installed docker+tensorflow. I tried to run one of the example MNIST using jupyter. But it always gives me the error below.

"The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically"

I checked the error message in cmd window. it says ".ipynb file not trusted" like below,

[image]

Comment: The 'not trusted' message shouldn't be a problem, and it's not related to the kernel dying. There's nothing there that indicates why the kernel died.

Comment: So what could I do to fix the kernel problem?

Comment: No idea - I'm not familiar with tensorflow, and there's no error message to indicate the problem. I'm just letting you know that the messages about trust are a red herring.